# Phpfox Register Page Plugin Call

Tags: plugins, phpfox

Can someone please explain this piece of code works in phpfox {plugin call='user.template_default_block_register_step2_7'}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
plugins are works in phpfox as a hook.
to add your custom code with in default phpfox system without changing any file we used plugin.

{plugin call='user.template_default_block_register_step2_7'}

to use this plugin you must create a file name user.template_default_block_register_step2_7.php

in any module even in your custom module.

what ever you write in this file it's automatically added where this plugin call.

you can add multiple plugin with same name in different module.

plugin file path

module_name/include/plugin/
```

Answer (score 0):

It will include a block file in the following location,that block file has the registration page.

```
www/projectname/Module/user/template/default/block/register/step2.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift response. Yes am aware of that. Aparently, my question was not detailed enough. The last two character(_7) is my major concern actually. Thanks again.